# Gamecenter Leaderboard higher score doesnt update when sent

Tags: xcode, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

My code successfully works in sending the score to the Gamecenter leaderboard, and worked exactly as expected in Sandbox mode.

However now that the app is released, only the first score the player got is displayed on the leaderboard yet higher scores are getting sent to it and not displayed.

Has any come across this before? Any possible solution/reconfigurations?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with the way iTunes connect is set up, check you leaderboard setting and make sure 'Score Submission Type' is set to 'Best Score' and 'Sort Order' is set to 'High To Low'